# Show and Hide DOM elements based off of text input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I have an angular app which perform an operation and displays data in a table once so many characters are in the input text box. I am trying to figure out how I can show and hide the tables based off of how many characters are typed inside of the input box.

```
<head>
<script>
      angular.module('minLength', [])
         .controller("SomeController ", ['$scope ', function($scope) {
            $scope.minlength = 3; 
         }];
    </script>
</head>
<div ng-controller="SomeController">
    <input type="text" id="foo" name="input" ngMinLength="minlength" ng-keydown="some.operation()" ng-model="some.model">


    <div id="table 1 >
    <!--content -->

    </div>


    <div id="table 2">
    <!-- content -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Any suggestions? Should I even use ng-show or is there a better way to do what I am trying to do.

Comment: `ng-if="some.model.length > 42"`, etc.

Comment: You could try to get the data once the user has entered some number of characters and then set it on $scope and data bind it in the table instead of showing or hiding content if you want to show both the tables otherwise you can use any of ng-switch, ng-show/ng-hide or ng-if directives.

Comment: @raina77ow that did the trick

Answer (score 2):

You could use `$scope.$watch` to set a flag as well as run your operation. Then you don't need the `ng-keydown` attribute.

```
// In HTML
<div ng-show="dataAvailable">
    <div id="table1">
    </div>
    <div id="table2">
    </div>
</div>

// In controller
$scope.$watch("some.model", function(newVal) {
    if (newVal.length >= 3) {
        $scope.dataAvailable = true;
        // some.operation
    } else {
        $scope.dataAvailable = false;
    }
});
```

[Plunker Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/R6I0Dxk9GUdRucT8chi6?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

Just using HTML to show/hide table:

```
<div ng-show="some.model.length >= minlength">
    <div id="table 1 >
        <!--content -->
    </div>

    <div id="table 2">
        <!-- content -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Code is attached below and assumed that minLength is 4.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.5/angular.js"></script>
<script>
      angular.module('minLength', [])
         .controller("SomeController", ['$scope', function($scope) {
            var minlength = 4; 
            $scope.some = {model: null,
               operation: function() {
                $scope.showTable1 = this.model && this.model.length > minlength;
                                $scope.showTable2 = $scope.showTable1;
            }};


         }]);
    </script>
<body ng-app="minLength">

<div ng-controller="SomeController">
    <input type="text" id="foo" name="input" ng-change="some.operation()" ng-model="some.model">


    <div id="someTable" ng-if="showTable1">
    <!--content -->
     <table>
      <tr>
        <td>ssasas</td>
        <td> AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    </div>
<hr>

    <div id="table 2" ng-if="showTable2">
    <!-- content -->
<table>
      <tr>
        <td>VVVVVVVV</td>
        <td>AAAAAAAAAA</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Hope it will resolve your issue.